# Report which element is being processed in a for loop

Tags: unix, for-loop

Suppose I have a directory with some subdirectories and some files within those I'm gzipping.

Here's the command I use:

```
for DATA in 9372161117 9372161118 9372161119 9372161153 9372161162 9372161163 9372161174 9372161189 9372161202 9372953017 9372953023 9372953024 9372953041 9372953049 9372953050 9372953053 9372953060 9374339086 9374339107 9374339128 9374339140 9374344040 9374344041 9374344138 9374345027 9374363112 9374363116 9374363117 9374363139 9374364101 9374365025 9374365109 9374365129 9374365160 9374682068 9374682069 9374682130 9374683008 9374683019 9374683020 9374683043 9374683044 9374683045 ; do 
    echo "Processing *.idat-files in folder ${DATA}..."; 
    gzip -v ${DATA}/*.idat; 
    echo "========================"; 
    echo ""; 
done
```

I know how to report back which element in the list of `DATA` is being processed. But my question: can I get a number with that? So the report back would be something like: "processing directory number 1: 9372161117", "processing directory number 2: 9372161118" etc.

Comment: just keep track of it with a counter. `i=0` and then in the `for` loop say `((i++))`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Keep the iteration number in `i` then print & increment it on every iteration:

```
i=1;
for DATA in 9372161117 9372161118 9372161119 9372161153 9372161162 9372161163 9372161174 9372161189 9372161202 9372953017 9372953023 9372953024 9372953041 9372953049 9372953050 9372953053 9372953060 9374339086 9374339107 9374339128 9374339140 9374344040 9374344041 9374344138 9374345027 9374363112 9374363116 9374363117 9374363139 9374364101 9374365025 9374365109 9374365129 9374365160 9374682068 9374682069 9374682130 9374683008 9374683019 9374683020 9374683043 9374683044 9374683045 ; do 
    echo "Processing directory number ${i}: ${DATA} ";
    echo "Processing *.idat-files in folder ${DATA}..."; 
    gzip -v ${DATA}/*.idat; 
    echo "========================"; 
    echo ""; 
    ((i++));
done
```

Comment: `i = 1;` is wrong, this will try to execute the command `i` with parameters `=` and `1`. Instead, you need to say `i=1`. Also, there is no need to use semi colons at the end of each line.

Comment: @fedorqui fixed the `i=1`, thanks. The semicolons are for conveniance and following the OP usage.